# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello Community I have a problem and I dont know how to solve it my problem is I write a script to crawl webpages for Images with BeautifuleSoup4 but I got the error  (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group')

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://www.fotocommunity.de/natur/wolken/3144?sort=new'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img', {"src": True})

urls = [img["src"] for img in img_tags]

for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'([\w_-]+[.](jpg|png))$', url)
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:

        if 'http' not in url:
            # sometimes an image source can be relative
            # if it is provide the base url which also happens
            # to be the site variable atm.
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: This means that your regex search for `filename` returned no results. Test for its truthiness with an `if` first.

Comment: yet I have the Problem that I dont get any Photo and no error :/

Comment: Because your regex is wrong. I am guessing you only want the filename?

Comment: yes I only want to have the filename . Sorry it is my first crawler :)

Comment: Cool. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. Use Python's internal `urllib` to do the heavyweight lifting instead of writing regexes if you're not familiar with them.

Use something like this (untested):

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlsplit  # import this additional library
from os.path import basename  # import this additional library

site = 'https://www.fotocommunity.de/natur/wolken/3144?sort=new'

response = requests.get(site)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
images_div = soup.find(id=re.compile(r"fcx-gallery-\w+"))  # focus on the div containing the images
if img_tags:  # test if img_tags has any data
    img_tags = images_div.find_all('img', {"data-src": True})  # get all the images in that div

    urls = [img["data-src"] for img in img_tags]  # grab sources from data-source

    for url in urls:
        filename = basename(urlsplit(url).path)  # use this instead of a regex
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:  # filename is now a string

            if 'http' not in url:
                # sometimes an image source can be relative
                # if it is provide the base url which also happens
                # to be the site variable atm.
                url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
            response = requests.get(url)
            f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: cool it works but yet I dont get every Photo only 10 but I need a bit "more" :D

Comment: Have you checked how many `urls` you have? I tested your code up to line 13 and there are 6 urls.

Comment: where do you find this much urls  I can only find the urls Tag and the url for the crawling

Comment: Now I get this error (KeyError: 'src') I know I must allow it first but where ?

Comment: My bad. I removed `{"src": True}` by mistake.

Comment: here we go again the same error than at the beginning but with an another attribute (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all')

Comment: Well the images are now hidden inside a `data-src` tag because the site renders them with JavaScript later. I edited the answer. Should work now.

Comment: I only tested it up until the line that gets the `urls` list and for me it works. I didn't test the image retrieval. Now I added an `if` in there, however check if you even get anything in the `soup`. You will have to debug this on your own from hereon, I can't help you any further.